# Boost ptree get<std::string>() return non printable characters?

Tags: boost, ascii, stdmap

I was wondering if it is possible for the ptree get function if called like:
`get<std::string>("string")` on a JSON string to return non-printable characters? And if so, how do I filter thenm out best?
The problem I'm seeing is that I isnert the strings into a `std::map` and every instance thereafter should just update the original entry but what happens is that I end up with multiple entries in the end.
 I use `if (mymap->insert(std::make_pair(str, dat)).second == false){` (where `str` is what comes out of the above `get()` function) to check for existing entries - or insert a new one.
`dat` is a strcture of data associated with the `str` that should be updated if it the entry exists already (which happens in the `false` case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible for the ptree get function if called like:
>   get("string") on a JSON string to return non-printable characters?

It is not possible to call `get<std::string>` on a (JSON) string. You **can** however call it on a `ptree` and of course it can return data. So, if that data contains non-printables, then they're in your data.

> I use `if (mymap->insert(std::make_pair(str, dat)).second == false){` (where `str` is what comes out of the above `get()` function) to check for existing entries - or insert a new one.

That's the correct way - assuming that your keys equivalence¹ is indeed given by `std::less<std::string>`.

> dat is a strcture of data associated with the str that should be updated if it the entry exists already (which happens in the false case).

In that case, consider **not** checking for existence, but indeed just updating:

```
 mymap[str] = dat;
```

This will automatically insert a new element if the key wasn't already there. Note that this will **not** change the behaviour with regards to the keys.

### Demo

Simplify to check your understanding:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcd1ac1748e82566)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct dat {
    int i, j, k;
};

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, dat const& d) {
    return os << "{" << d.i << "," << d.j << "," << d.k << "}";
}

using Map = std::map<std::string, dat>;

void dump(Map const& m) {
    std::cout << " --- Map: \n";
    for (auto& entry : m) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(entry.first) << " -> " << entry.second << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    Map mymap {
        { "one", {1,2,3} },
        { "two", {2,4,6} },
        { "three", {3,6,9} },
    };

    dump(mymap);

    mymap["four"] = {4,8,12}; // adds
    dump(mymap);

    mymap["three"] = {0,0,0}; // overwrites
    dump(mymap);

    mymap["three "] = {-1,-1,-1}; // adds new key
    dump(mymap);
}
```

Prints

```
 --- Map: 
"one" -> {1,2,3}
"three" -> {3,6,9}
"two" -> {2,4,6}
 --- Map: 
"four" -> {4,8,12}
"one" -> {1,2,3}
"three" -> {3,6,9}
"two" -> {2,4,6}
 --- Map: 
"four" -> {4,8,12}
"one" -> {1,2,3}
"three" -> {0,0,0}
"two" -> {2,4,6}
 --- Map: 
"four" -> {4,8,12}
"one" -> {1,2,3}
"three" -> {0,0,0}
"three " -> {-1,-1,-1}
"two" -> {2,4,6}
```

---

¹ weak total ordering